# retro create a git repository from backup dirs

Tags: git, backup

I have several backup dirs I want to put them into git.

The dirs are:

```
web_backup_2012-03-07
web_backup_2012-06-03
web_backup_2012-06-21
web_backup_2012-06-25
web_backup_2012-07-02
web_backup_2012-07-15
web_backup_2012-07-21
```

now I want to put them on git. What's the best way?
(each backup is about 1.1 G, 20k files.)

Here's what I think should do:

• cd to the earliest backup dir.

```
git init
git add .
git commit . -m"initial commit"
```

then move the .git dir into the second dir, then do

```
git add .
git commit . -m"commit. ‹date here›"
```

repeat the above.

Then, when in the last dir, I'm done. I can delete all previous backup dirs. (I can then move the .git dir into my current working web dir and repeat. So that my web dir with history is all in git now.)

From my test, each step will take 10 minutes.

I am new to git. Plus is if anyone can tell me whether/how to also add a tag of date (if it is good for this.)

Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you want to list all the backup files within one git repository, or individual repositories for each backup?

Comment: I think you might run into problems with deleted files in between backups.

Comment: @mirk ah yes. How do i resolve deleted files? (other than painfully manually do diff and git rm)

Comment: @RobertH yes all in one repository.

Comment: @XahLee see my answer, that should get you up and running, mind you deleted files will still be a pain to deal with...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than `git add .`, which will always add files, I recommend `git add -A` which will "find new files as well as staging modified content and removing files that are no longer in the working tree" (from the [git docs](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html)).

I'd write a script that looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
git init
GIT_DIR=$(pwd)
for dir in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -name web_backup_\* | sort); do
  pushd $dir
  git add -A
  git commit -m "Backup for $dir."
  git tag $dir
  popd
done
```

Comment: Rather than explicitly moving the `.git` directory around (and all the bookkeeping such as keeping track of `lastdir`), the environment variable `GIT_DIR` (or the command line switch `--git-dir`) is a more robust way to do this. Just set `GIT_DIR` to the location of `.git` directory before running the add/commit/tag sequence for each backup directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a repository with all backups in one directory do the following:

```
1. cd to parent directory and run git init
2. run git add *
3. run git commit -a -m "initial commit" 
4. run git push -u <repository> master
```

To use a full example using bitbucket as the provider you could do:

```
git init
git remote add origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/username/repositoryname.git
git add *
git commit -a -m "Initial commit" 
git push -u origin master
```

Then when you want to push changes to the repo, you change to the parent directory and execute

```
 git commit -a -m "commit message"
 git push -u origin master
```

Also, if you are looking to see if anything has changed you can use: `git status` from the parent repository directory.

To see what the changes are, try `gitk` from the parent directory.

Comment: thank you. Correct me if i'm wrong, this put all the backup dir into one git repository and each backup dir is a subdir right? I want each backup to be historical commits.

Comment: Correct, it will mirror the setup you have on your local directory